# Are Cyanogenmod nightlies compatible with latest vendor images?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-5x

I am about to install Cyanogenmod 13 nightlies on my Nexus5x and was wondering how I can find out which vendor.img is required for which nightly?

thanks!

Comment: Can you just use this guide to install CM13? https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_bullhead.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab: if i follow this guide, then i get an unrecoverable error message at the first boot saying that there is a mismatch in vendor image.

Comment: Why not just download the latest `vendor.img` then from here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#bullhead and flash it with `‘fastboot flash vendor vendor.img`

Comment: thats exactly what i did and this leads to the error. thats why i am asking which vendor.img exactly i need. cause it seems its not the latest.

Answer (score 2):

You generally need the latest vendor image but since we (CM), unlike Google, support all CM13 devices using the same code branch the build number you see in Settings -> About doesn't always match up with the build number you see for the stock images.

Solution: Run 'getprop | grep fingerprint' on a terminal on the device or via adb shell. From the output, compare "ro.build.fingerprint" and "ro.vendor.build.fingerprint" values. Those must match for the message to disappear.﻿